# Custom navigation view GPS marker

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, marker

How can we customize the default arrow icon(GPS icon) that is shown during navigation?I would like to add my own icon to track the user movement.I am using Mapbox and navigationview

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for checking out the navigation SDK - this is definitely customizable, check out our documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/navigation-ui/#styling-the-navigationview).

In particular, letter `H`.  You need to set a custom style for the `LocationComponent`.